# Can I replace Sitecore Email Sending Service?

Tags: email, smtp, sitecore

By default smtp server can be configed in Sitecore web.config. However is it possible to hijack the whole email sending part to use a different method instead of a smtp server? Is there some kind of pipeline?

For example, I want to use another web service to send all emails, or I want to save all of them into a database instead of actually sending them?

Also a different question would be, does content delivery instance need to send emails by default? I would assume all out-of-box email sending are from content authoring instance right?

And from my understanding, there's only workflows in Sitecore need to send emails and it can be customized by changing the email action. (Assume no Email Campaign Modules, no Webform for Markets module and etc.)

Any insight would be great help, thanks!

--------------Update---------------------29/09/2015--------------

I have got my answers, thanks everyone.

Basically I shouldn't need to working about the smtp server on CDS instances, and all email sending can be controlled by pipelines on CAS instances.

However when I checked the source code, there's only one place "Reminder" which uses the smtp server to send emails directly. So if this function is important to you, you should consider update this function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes absolutely.

At runtime when you are defining the `SMTPClient` you can set the properties for the server by the following code

```cs
SmtpClient client=new SmtpClient("Host");
client.Credentials=new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.from="sender@gmail.com";
mailMessage.To.Add("recipient@gmail.com");
mailMessage.body="body";
mailMessage.subject="subject";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

What you can do, instead of having the values hardcoded in the code you can retrieve the values from Sitecore Items and use those, this will allow greater control for Content Editors and even use different SMTP Server in different parts of functionality.

```cs
Item emailItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("Id of Item");

string from = emailItem["From"];
string to = emailItem["To"];
string server = emailItem["Mail server"];
string subject = emailItem["Subject"];
string message = emailItem["Message"];
```

There is a `SendEmail` `pipeline` apart of Sitecore's `EXM` aka `ECM` which you can override if you take the `EXM` route. It has two `processors` `FillEmail` and `SendEmail` which you can utilise or remove and add your own `processor` for actually sending the message.

It is possible to save the emails to a database, or rather the content, instead of sending them. This can be achieved by custom code in Sitecore or `Webforms for Marketers` which has `Save Actions` for Sending Emails or Saving to a Database and its really simple to configure.

As you said there is no need to send emails on every occasion its more about determining what you are trying to achieve and if Sending Emails, Saving to Database etc is more relevant. The great thing about Sitecore is you can create `Items` programmatically and store the information there, save you worrying about creating database tables, managing `ConnectionStrings`, setting up `EntityFramework` etc.

Here is a simple blog on [creating Sitecore Items Programmatically](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/06/ProgramaticallyItems2.aspx).

Sitecore Workflow sending Emails is optional and can be removed by deleting the `Send Email` `CommandAction` Item from beneath the `WorkflowState` Item and then publish.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it's fine if the email sending is from my code. I was trying to find out the internal Sitecore Email Sending places where uses smtp servers and want to see if I can hijack those. However your later answer regarding the EXM, workflow and WFFM kinda of answered my question, basically if there isn't any custom email sending in website, all email sending are from CAS where mainly can be setup using piepelines.

Comment: Yup - you can send it up via Pipelines. Its worth knowing that WFFM, Workflow and EXM all contain MailSettings fields on Items (Mail server, From, To Subject, Username, Password etc). WFFM on the Send Email Save Action, Workflow on the Send Email action Item  and EXM on the Messanger Updates email Item. So you enter your details for CAS there

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to intercept *all* emails is to configure Sitecore to send all emails to the locally hosted SMTP server (127.0.0.1) and then grab them from there using your custom code.

There is a lot of free SMTP servers, just make sure you test them with high volume of emails before moving to production.